# Is there a template for Facilitator Task Sheet for a Multi-user Testing Project?

Tags: usability-testing, usability-study

I'm going to be running an in-person Multi-User Testing Project with multiple facilitators.
I have tasks and questions for the facilitators to run through the project but am looking for a template for the tasks or an example of how the task sheet should be outlined.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a template for organizing tasks and questions for a multi-user testing project would include the following elements:

- A brief introduction or overview of the project, including its goals
  and objectives, the user groups being tested, and any key assumptions
  or hypotheses being tested.
- A list of the tasks that will be conducted during the project, along
  with detailed instructions on how to perform each task and any
  relevant materials or resources that facilitators will need.
- A set of standardized questions or prompts that facilitators can use
  to guide the user through each task and elicit feedback and insights.
  These questions should be open-ended and designed to encourage users
  to share their thoughts and experiences in their own words.
- A set of standardized observations or notes that facilitators can use
  to document the user's behavior, reactions, and feedback during each
  task. These observations should be objective and focused on capturing
  the user's experience and responses, rather than the facilitator's
  personal impressions or interpretations.
- A set of standardized debrief questions or prompts that facilitators
  can use to review the user's experience and feedback at the end of
  each task. These questions should be designed to help facilitators
  identify common themes and patterns across the user group, and to
  identify any potential areas for improvement or further
  investigation.